# translating some pseudocode

Tags: python

So I am creating a program to generate pascal's triangle, which I know has been done to death, however the way I am told to go about it is different then how I would have thought.  I am just needing some help translating the beginning so that I can get it rolling.  It basically states assign a list to be empty to represent the triangle and
for each row of the triangle from 0 to the height+1 assign a list to be empty to represent one new row of the triangle.If the new row is row zero make the new row to be a [1].

So what I have so far is

```
h=input("enter height")
mytri=[]
for i in range(0,h+1):
    row=[ ] 
    if i==0:
        newrow=[1]
    elif newrow==1:
    #here is where I get lost
```

Where I am having trouble is finding out how to tell if the new row is row zero or row 1.  Have yet to see anything like that in my short experience with python.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does `if i==0` not work, or am I missing the question?

Comment: You'd probably want to use a `for` loop to create lists of size n, n + 1, n + 2... n + k and append them to your master list.

Comment: On the last line of your code, you need just an `else:`

Comment: Did you know that you can also write `if i==0` as `if not i`? Check out how that works.

Comment: How did you think you should have gone about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third line, you are running a `for` loop, so that will be a `for` there instead of an `if`.

Coming to your question, you need to know the row number and check whether it is something, right? Look carefully, what variable in your code corresponds to the row number?

Comment: the i? and yes sorry that was i typo for if instead of for.. i fixed it

Comment: so if i==0:  but then how would I say if i ==0 then new row = 1  newrow=[1]?

Comment: then the next step where it says if newrow=1 then newrow to be [1,1]  I am unsure if that is suppose to be newrow=[1,1] or like newrow1=[1,1]?  Also how would I check to see if a column in that row is 0? its asking for each column in row.. only thing i can tell is for column in row:  ??????